# Cant create preferences activity in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, preferences, deprecated

I am trying to make a preferences activity in android. What happens is you start the app and the you press the menu or settings button on your phone while in the app. Preferences should be on of the categories you can chose from. the problem is when I tap preferences the application crashes. Can someon please fix and repaste my code.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;

public class Prefs extends PreferenceActivity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);
}



}
```

I am aware I am using a deprecated method, I tried going to the android.developers website and I couldnt find an answer

Here is my XML:

```
<EditTextPreference 
    android:title="EditText"
    android:key="name"
    android:summary="Enter Your Name"
    />

<CheckBoxPreference 
    android:title="CheckBox"
    android:defaultValue="true"
    android:key="checkbox"
    android:summary="check this box"
    />

<ListPreference 
    android:title="list"
    android:key="list"
    android:summary="This is a list to choose from"
    android:entries="@+array/list"
    android:entryValues="@+array/lvalues"
    ></ListPreference>
```

Comment: what error you get?? post yout Log here...

Comment: have you tried the undeprecated method (using PreferenceFragment)?